Does `pub fn long(&self) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'static` leak data with every created future?
Basically, building on this answer:
pub fn long() -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'static {
  let s = String::from("what is the answer?");
  async move {
     // `s` gets moved into this block
     println!("{s}");
  }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let future = long(); // Create the future
    future.await; // Await the future, it will complete, and `s` will be dropped
}

My question is whether this 'static bound will leak data with every created future? Or does the 'static bound here mean that the trait implementation has to be static? (e.g. where the function definitions are in memory). So far I have:

asked ChatGPT: it says that awaiting drops the future
the paragraph from the book doesn't answer.
read the rustonomicon on lifetime coercion
read similar questions

I'm mainly trying to conceptualize the need and effects of 'static; the code works already.
background
I have a reader that can read some parts, while for another it may need to load additional data into itself before continuing. The best thing I've come up with is:
type Image = Vec<u8>;
#[async_trait]
trait Reader {
    async fn read_into_buffer(&self, offset: u32, buf: &mut [u8]) {
       sleep(2);
       buf.fill(42);
    }
}

struct Decoder<R: Reader> {
  reader: Arc<R>,
  images: HashMap<u32, Arc<Image>>,
}

impl<R> Decoder<R> {
  fn decode_chunk(&self, overview: u32, chunk: usize) -> Result<(),impl Future<Output = Vec<u8>> {
    if let Some(im) = self.images.get(overview) {
      // cheap clones because they are Arcs
      let image = im.clone()
      let r = self.reader.clone()
      async move {
        // don't mention `self` in here
        let buf = vec![0; 42];
        let offset = image[chunk];
        r.read_into_buffer(offset, buf);
        buf
      }
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
  }

  async fn load_overview(&mut self, offset: u32) {
    let buf = vec![0;42];
    self.reader.read_into_buffer(offset, buf).await;
    self.images.insert(offset, buf);
  }
}

which could be used like:
decoder.load_overview(42).await;
let chunk_1 = decoder.decode_chunk(42, 13).unwrap(); // no await'ing
let chunk_2_err = decoder.decode_chunk(13).unwrap_err(); // chunk 13 isn't loaded
decoder.load_overview(13).await;
let chunk_2 = decoder.decode_chunk(13, 13).unwrap();
let res = (chunk_1.await, chunk_2.await)


For the title, the answer is no, but I can't really explain the details very well. So good question, +1.

'static is not strict here, fn long<'a>() -> Future<Output = ()> + 'a works as well. FWIW, in edition 2024, there is a new RPIT lifetime capture rules allows the lifetime to be omitted.

Lifetimes are never prescriptive, only declarative. So a lifetime annotation cannot change the behaviour of the code, all it can do is give information about how the existing code is expected to behave. If the compiler notices a discrepancy between the code and the lifetimes, then it doesn't change the behaviour but emits an error instead.

There is no memory leak. Heap-allocated contents, like s, will be dropped before the .await completes. The stack allocation of the future will go out of scope when .await completes.
You can imagine the returned Future<Output = ()> + 'static as a state machine, like this enum:
enum ReturnedFuture {
    Created{s: String},
    Done
}

This enum, which is 'static on account of no non-'static references, implements Future like this (I've artificially simplified the method signature a lot):
impl Future for ReturnedFuture {
    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<()> {
         match self {
              Self::Created{s} => {
                  println!("{s}");
                  // Here is where `s` (heap allocation) will be automatically dropped.
                  *self = Self::Done;
              }
              Self::Done => {}
         }
         Poll::Ready(())
    }
}

You can imagine .await being implemented like this (the complexity of yielding Poll::Pending to async runtimes and registering to be woken up via Context's has been elided):
let future = long();
// future.await;
let result = {
    // future is moved to a mutable variable
    let mut fut = future;
    loop {
        let poll = fut.poll();
        if poll.is_ready() {
            break poll;
        } else {
            unreachable!("ReturnedFuture never returns pending, so this complexity has been elided");
        }
    }
    // fut goes out of scope here (stack allocation is dropped).
};
// future no longer exists here (it was moved already)

See the comments in the last two code blocks for when freeing of memory happens.

What does "which is 'static on account of no non-'static references" mean? That it is the non-static object(s) holding on to the enum (as references) that dictate when it is dropped? But then the enum is still there as a dangling ReturnedFuture::Done or does that automagically dissapear somehow?

Good question! 'static means different things depending on the context. When a type like an enum is 'static, that just means it doesn't use any non-static lifetimes. For example, enum Foo<'a> { Bar(&'a str), Baz(Foo2<'a>) } is not 'static as 'a is a non-'static lifetime. As for your second question, ReturnedFuture::Done lives on the caller's stack frame and will go out of scope (when .await finishes). I've updated my answer to make this explicit.

So, if I understand correctly, 'static (here?) means "not bounded by anything related to this function". Then, it is still dependent on the scope in which it is created? So in your example, there would actually be another scope around future (not fut) in which future is dropped at the end.

The only scope around future's declaration is the function itself. In my model implementation of .await, future is moved to fut in a narrower scope, meaning the contents are dropped when the narrower scope is done. If you tried to access future after, you would get an error. For example, this code doesn't compile: #[tokio::main] pub async fn main() {     let fut = std::future::ready(());     fut.await;     fut.await; }

@FinnBear To clarify, Foo<'a> can be 'static -- Foo<'static>. A type generic over one or more lifetimes can be 'static as long as all of the generic lifetimes also are. This also extends to types. Foo<T> can be 'static or not. Foo<&'a ()> for a non-'static 'a is not 'static, for example.

@Fee The best way to summarize this all is: when a type is bounded on 'static, it means that the type cannot contain any non-'static borrows. It may also be worth pointing out that the 'static bound on Future in the first code block in your question is redundant -- in this context the 'static bound is implicit.
